# Check for variable, if false, create object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I have a nested array with time values (in milliseconds). I want to create an object in case the array does not have an entry for that time value. Right now my code  is like this:

```
var start = data[0].nDate;  // time in milliseconds
var end = data[data.length-1].nDate;  // time in milliseconds

var nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d){ return d.zone}) // id
    .key(function(d){return d.nDate})  // time in milliseconds
    .rollup(function(v){return {
        density: v[0].density,
        nDate: v[0].nDate,
        zone: v[0].zone,
        type: "zone"
    }})
    .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .sortValues(function(a,b){return a.date - b.date})
    .entries(data);

for (var i=start;i<end; i++){

    nestedData .forEach(function(b,j){
        var oneZone = +b.values[j].key; // time in milliseconds
        var o = {
            type: "nozone",
            zone: +b.key,  // id
            nDate: i,
            density: 0,
        };

        if(+(oneZone) != i){
            noZone.push(o)
        }
    })
}

//push calculations into a new array
nestedZones.forEach(function(d,i){
    var oneZone = d.values;
    for (var b=0; b<oneZone.length;b++){
        var timeZone = (oneZone[b].value);
        densityByZone.push(timeZone);
    }

});

noZone.forEach(function(d){densityByZone.push(d)});
```

Right now, the conditional does not work. Sometimes, it creates entries for times that already have objects.

Comment: Where is `noZone` defined? Also, please copy/paste your data (just a few rows), so it'd be easier to test a solution.

Comment: HI, `noZone` is an empty array defined before all the code mentioned earlier, sorry I didn't add it. 

The original data would look like this:
`0: Object { date: Sun Mar 26 2017 16:30:00; density: 0.04; nDate: 1656178` (time in milliseconds) `surface: 8000; zone: 99}` `1: Object { date: Sun Mar 26 2017 17:00:00; density: 0.02; nDate: 1656180; surface: 2550;  zone: 99 }`

The idea is that if there is no entry for a specific time (in this case 16:45), to make a new object with same id for that specific time.

I have 15 different ids with entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your code is using a nested loop in such a way that you'll create entries for objects that already have that "time". That's the expected behaviour if you use a `forEach` inside a for loop that way.

Instead of that, I suggest you create an array with all the "times"...

```
var nDateArray = d3.range(start, end + 1, 1);
```

... and use a function like this to populate `noZone`:

```
nestedData.forEach(function(e) {
    nDateArray.filter(function(f) {
        return e.values.map(function(g) {
            return +g.key
        }).indexOf(f) === -1;
    }).forEach(function(h) {
        noZone.push({
            type: "nozone",
            zone: +e.key, // id
            nDate: h,
            density: 0,
        })
    })
})
```

Here is a demo with that small array you shared in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638640/check-for-variable-if-false-create-object?noredirect=1#comment76429914_44638640):

```js
var data = [{
  date: "Sun Mar 26 2017 16:30:00",
  density: 0.04,
  nDate: 1656178,
  surface: 8000,
  zone: 99
}, {
  date: "Sun Mar 26 2017 17:00:00",
  density: 0.02,
  nDate: 1656180,
  surface: 2550,
  zone: 99
}];

var noZone = [];
var start = data[0].nDate; // time in milliseconds
var end = data[data.length - 1].nDate; // time in milliseconds
var nDateArray = d3.range(start, end + 1, 1);

var nestedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.zone
  }) // id
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.nDate
  }) // time in milliseconds
  .rollup(function(v) {
    return {
      density: v[0].density,
      nDate: v[0].nDate,
      zone: v[0].zone,
      type: "zone"
    }
  })
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
  .sortValues(function(a, b) {
    return a.date - b.date
  })
  .entries(data);

nestedData.forEach(function(e) {
  nDateArray.filter(function(f) {
    return e.values.map(function(g) {
      return +g.key
    }).indexOf(f) === -1;
  }).forEach(function(h) {
    noZone.push({
      type: "nozone",
      zone: +e.key, // id
      nDate: h,
      density: 0,
    })
  })
})

console.log(noZone)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```